# Get the Identity of the current Principal

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication, impersonation

I have this piece of code that determines the identity of a user accessing my aspx page running under a Virtual Directory in the website(Windows Authentication in IIS).This is used to access folders on a remote server. Each user's access permission is different for different files and folders on the remote server.

> System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext
>   impersonationContext;  impersonationContext =
>   ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

My question: Is there an alternate method to using this code? If I only have the username and domain,can I impersonate the user?